# When converting String to Int type and print that Int type in console then show an error "Unexpectedly found nil while unwraping an optional value"?

Tags: ios, swift, optional-values

When converting String to Int type and print that Int type in console then show an error

> Unexpectedly found nil while unwraping an optional value

ViewController.swift

```
    @IBAction func btnVerifyOTP(_ sender: Any)
    {
          let verifyOTP = 
          self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VerifyOTP") as! VerifyOTP
          self.navigationController?.pushViewController(verifyOTP, animated: true)
          verifyOTP.strPhone = self.tfMobile.text!
    }
```

ViewController2.swift

```
class VerifyOTP: UIViewController {

var strPhone = String()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

       let numPhone = Int(strPhone)!
       print(numPhone)
    }
}
```

Error :  This method will print "Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value"

Comment: what is the value of self.tfMobile.text?

Comment: And how you are sure about that a valid integer has been inserted in the   `tfMobile`? obviously, if its text isn't a valid int no doubt you would get such an error.

Comment: self.tfMobile.text  is the text in the text field.

Comment: when i print that string in ViewController2 then it shows correctly in the console. But when i convert this string into Int type, and print that then it shows an error (Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value)

Comment: You should never forcily unwrap an optional, it will cause a crash

Comment: Replace `let numPhone = Int(strPhone)!` with `let numPhone = Int(strPhone)?`

Comment: Change the order: First set `strPhone` in the controller, than push it. Basically the code crashes if the string cannot be converted to `Int`. An empty string as default value is nonsensical because it can **not** be converted to `Int` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems lies in the initialization order:
What happens is that`viewDidLoad` is executed before `verifyOTP.strPhone = self.tfMobile.text!` is executed (because of `pushViewController`).

This means that `strPhone` is an empty string, and `Int(strPhone)` returns `nil`, so forced unwrapping will crash.

You might want to change the execution order in `btnVerifyOTP`:

```
@IBAction func btnVerifyOTP(_ sender: Any)
{
    let verifyOTP = 
    self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "VerifyOTP") as! VerifyOTP
    verifyOTP.strPhone = self.tfMobile.text!
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(verifyOTP, animated: true)
}
```

You should also do some `nil` checking in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
if let numPhone = Int(strPhone) {
     print(numPhone)
}
```

Comment: yes all code is executed, only when i convert this into Int type then it shows an error